# sharepoint lists - identical permission list - different user access

Tags: 2007, permissions

Sharepoint 2007 SP3 with December CU. One site, two lists. Permissions are not inherited and looks like these:

```
List1:
group1 - contribute
group2 - read
portal owners - full control

List2:
group3 - contribute
group4 - read
portal owners - full control
```

The problem's that List1 can access only users from group1, group2 and portal owners, but to List2 all users have read access!

If I create a new list on the same site or on a new site then everyone will have read access to it no matter what's in permission list. But if I set a custom permissions on an item in a list then it works as it should be.

Anonymous login is disabled in Cental administration for this application. Windows log is clear.

What else could it be?

Comment: have you the group1 or 2 inside the group3 or 4?

Comment: no, they are not

Comment: the worst part of it that I cannot create a new list with limited read permission on it. All users'll have read permission to it!

Comment: But I must add that it happens only with document libraries, normal lists work fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally made it. Turning off anonymous access Central Administration only disable the ability to change this option on a Sharepoint sites, but not actually turns it off. So I had to turn in back on, then disable anonymous access on all sites including root site and turn if off again.